# Pointer arithmetic around cast

Tags: c, casting, pointer-arithmetic

I am currently enrolled in a CS107 class which makes the following assumptions:

- `sizeof(int) == 4`
- `sizeof(short) == 2`
- `sizeof(char) == 1`
- big endianness

My professor showed the following code:

```
int arr[5];
((short*)(((char*) (&arr[1])) + 8))[3] = 100;
```

Here are the 20 bytes representing `arr`:

```
|....|....|....|....|....|
```

My professor states that `&arr[1]` points here, which I agree with.

```
|....|....|....|....|....|
     x
```

I now understand that `(char*)` makes the pointer the width of a char (1 byte) instead of the width of an int (4 bytes).

What I don't understand is the `+ 8`, which my professor says points here:

```
|....|....|....|....|....|
                         x
```

But shouldn't it point here, since it is going forwards 8 times the size of a char (1 byte)?

```
|....|....|....|....|....|
               x
```

Comment: You are right. Write some code to print the values of the pointers to show your professor that you are right.

Comment: It all depends on `sizeof(int)`, which is not necessarily `4`.

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev My professor stated to assume that `sizeof(int)` is 4 for the duration of the class. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Alexey - 1, Professor - 0.

Comment: You had better ask the Prof whether the "supposed" machine is little or big-endian too.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, another thing I omitted, this is supposed to be big endian.

Comment: Somewhat related: This is the classic example of a strict aliasing violation, so this code doesn't have any well-defined semantics anyway.

Comment: @mafso. Very true. He was alright until he cast to `short*`. He's declaration to be big-endian clears up most realistic questions about semantics but it is still Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take it step by step. Your expression can be decomposed like this:

```
((short*)(((char*) (&arr[1])) + 8))[3]
-----------------------------------------------------
char *base = (char *) &arr[1];
char *base_plus_offset = base + 8;
short *cast_into_short = (short *) base_plus_offset;
cast_into_short[3] = 100;
```

`base_plus_offset` points at byte location `12` within the array. `cast_into_short[3]` refers to a `short` value at location `12 + sizeof(short) * 3`, which, in your case is `18`.

Comment: And that's why code like that shouldn't be written on one line. Here it is crystal clear what's going on. In the code in the question, I'd assume the professor confused himself with too many parentheses.

Comment: @gnasher729: Or at least avoid totally useless parens like `(char *)(&arr[1])` (which seems to be here for people not knowing that a cast can take a unary expression, what, if it weren't allowed, wouldn't compile without the parens anyway; the doubt this "clarifies" even can't be expressed in terms of precedence). Though I agree that it probably should be split in this case.

Comment: @mafso: The second pair of parentheses are also useless, so the non-cargo-cult version of that expression would be: `((short *) ((char *) &arr[1] + 8))[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that can show you which byte gets modified on your system, along with a breakdown of what is happening:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    int arr[5];
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        arr[i] = 0;

    printf( "Before: " );

    for( i = 0; i < sizeof(int)*5; i++ )
        printf( "%2.2X ", ((char*)arr)[i] );

    printf( "\n" );

    ((short*)(((char*) (&arr[1])) + 8))[3] = 100;

    printf( "After: " );

    for( i = 0; i < sizeof(int)*5; i++ )
        printf( "%2.2X ", ((char*)arr)[i] );
    printf( "\n" );

    return 0;
}
```

Start from the inner most:

int pointer to (arr + 4)

```
&arr[1]
|...|...|...|...|...
    Xxxx
```

char pointer to (arr + 4)

```
(char*)(&arr[1])
|...|...|...|...|...
    X
```

char pointer to (arr + 4 + 8)

```
((char*)(&arr[1])) + 8)
|...|...|...|...|...
            X
```

short pointer to (arr + 4 + 8)

```
(short*)((char*)(&arr[1])) + 8)
|...|...|...|...|...
            Xx
```

short at (arr + 4 + 8 + (3 * 2)) (this is an array index)

```
((short*)((char*)(&arr[1])) + 8))[3]
|...|...|...|...|...
                  Xx
```

Exactly which byte gets modified here depends on the endianess of your system. On my little endian x86 I get the following output:

```
Before: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
After:  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 64 00
```

Good Luck with your course.

Comment: Your analysis of the expression is correct, but you seem to have misunderstood the OP's claim when you say he is not right.  His (one, so far) edit makes no difference, as the added cast to `short *` is not part of the subexpression he is inquiring about.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks, I've corrected that statement! Also add in the pointer position and memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

The expression will set the two bytes 18 bytes after the start of `arr` to the value 100.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int arr[5];

    char* start=(char*)&arr;
    char* end=(char*)&((short*)(((char*) (&arr[1])) + 8))[3];

    printf("sizeof(int)=%zu\n",sizeof(int));
    printf("sizeof(short)=%zu\n",sizeof(short));
    printf("offset=%td <- THIS IS THE ANSWER\n",(end-start));
    printf("100=%04x (hex)\n",100);

    for(size_t i=0;i<5;++i){

       printf("arr[%zu]=%d (%08x hex)\n",i,arr[i],arr[i]);

    }

}
```

Possible Output:

```
sizeof(int)=4
sizeof(short)=2
offset=18 <- THIS IS THE ANSWER
100=0064 (hex)
arr[0]=0 (00000000 hex)
arr[1]=0 (00000000 hex)
arr[2]=0 (00000000 hex)
arr[3]=0 (00000000 hex)
arr[4]=6553600 (00640000 hex)
```

In all your professors shenanigans he's shifted you 1 integer, 8 chars/bytes and 3 shorts that 4+8+6=18 bytes. Bingo.

Notice this output reveals the machine I ran this on to have 4 byte integers, 2 byte short (common) and be little-endian because the last two bytes of the array were set to 0x64 and 0x00 respectively.

I find your diagrams dreadfully confusing because it isn't very clear if you mean the '|' to be addresses or not.

```
|....|....|....|....|
012345678901234567890
    ^     1 ^     ^ 2
A   X       C     S B
```

Include the bars ('|') A is the start of `Arr` and B is 'one past the end' (a legal concept in C).

X is the address referred to by the expression &Arr[1].
C by the expression (((char*) (&arr[1])) + 8).
S by the whole expression.
S and the byte following are assigned to and what that means depends on the endian-ness of your platform.

I leave it as an exercise to determine what the output on a similar but big-endian platform who output. Anyone?
I notice from the comments you're big-endian and I'm little-endian (stop sniggering). 
You only need to change one line of the output.